# В чём разница между прокси и VPN?

Tags: сеть, безопасность, vpn, прокси

В чём разница между прокси и VPN?

Comment: VPN - шифрует. Прокси - кэширует.

Comment: @Akina прокси тоже может шифровать если это HTTPS-прокси. Так же как VPN может вовсе не заморачиваться шифрованием если это Garena.

Comment: @PavelMayorov А при чём тут "может"? Определяет то, что обязательно должно быть. Не шифрует? значит, не VPN. Не кэширует? Значит, не прокси. А то так можно  договориться до того, что микроскоп - это то, чем гвозди забивают... а заодно можно на что-нить мелкое поглазеть. Впрочем, есть и в твоих словах доля истины, сейчас термином "прокси" называют всё подряд, включая даже обычные NAT- маршрутизаторы.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Если рассматривать их в разрезе задачи скрытия своего адреса - то разница будет в  уровне [OSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_OSI).

Прокси-серверы работают на прикладном уровне, а VPN - на сетевом или даже канальном.

Но, вообще говоря, это совершенно разные технологии.

---

Прокси-сервер - это любой сервер который выполняет запрос пользователя от своего имени. Обычно прокси-сервер может работать только по одному протоколу.

Исключение - HTTPS-прокси, которые благодаря вызову CONNECT могут туннелировать любое TCP-соединение, и SOCKS5-прокси, способные передавать любые TCP и UDP пакеты.

Важным является тот факт, что нельзя так просто взять и подсунуть прокси любой программе - программа должна знать что она соединяется с сервером через прокси и как с этим прокси работать (исключение - реверс-прокси, которые притворяются сервером, и прозрачные прокси, которые перехватывают сетевой трафик; но с VPN вы их точно не перепутаете).

---

VPN же - это виртуальная сеть. Прямо как локальная сеть, только виртуальная. Обычно (за исключением особо кривых решений) подключение к VPN выглядит для программ как еще один сетевой адаптер у компьютера, поэтому при правильной настройке через VPN может работать любая программа даже не зная про существование этого VPN.

Как и в любой сети, в VPN может быть несколько маршрутизаторов, которые связывают ее с другими сетями (а может и не быть).

Answer (score 5):

Прокси (посредник) - это обычно какой-то прикладной протокол.
Т.е. имеется какая-то система-посредник, к которой надо явно обращаться, уговаривать её пересылать ваши запросы дальше к точке назначения.
A -> Proxy -> B

VPN - работает на более низком уровне. На сетевом, на канальном.
Взаимодействующие системы общаются непосредственно друг с другом, без посредника, используя привычные протоколы.
Они даже не подозревают, что соединение происходит по VPN.
A -> B